# How to capture a screenshot of a page using the given url in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to **react js**, can able to code basics. My goal is to take a screenshot of the target URL. I have googled almost and none worked for me.

Tried html2canvas, phantom, web shot but not working.

```
<html>
<div id="target">
    hello
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var canvas = document.getElementById("target");
  var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
</script>
</html>
```

Output  for the above snipet : canvas.toDataURL is not a function

I have a bunch of code written in js for other functionalities and I expect this functionality to be included in my script.So that I shouldn't run it externally unlike phantomjs.Finally, I link this script in all my HTML pages.

input: https://google.com

output: it should be captured and save the screenshot as an image in my local.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried with code, it's easier to help that way. This site isn't about just providing full working solutions - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TommyBs updated my post.can you help to sort the problem?

Comment: Did you try with phantom js? https://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: @AhmedRebai yes it worked but is there any way to take the screenshot without using phantomjs. I have a bunch of code written in js and i expect this functionality to be included in my script .so that I shouldn't run it externally.

Comment: Like you have included html2canvas, you can include phantomjs instead, can you share with me where it should be included?

Comment: @AhmedRebai, I need to include screenshot snippet here.window.onbeforeunload=function(event){ //called on navigating pages
  if(typeof event=='undefined'){
    event=window.event;
  }
  if(event){
    //screenshot snippet
  }
};

Answer (score 3):

Check this example using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js) in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekvjtb4q/). it may work for you

```
<div id="app"></div>

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const test = () => {
      html2canvas(document.querySelector("#app"))
         .then(function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg', 'image/octet-stream');
            console.log(base64URL, payload)
         });
    }

    return (
      <button onClick={test}>Button</button>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(event){
 if(typeof event=='undefined'){ event=window.event; }   

  if(event){ 

      var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://www.google.com/', function() {
  page.render('google.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
  }  

}
```

Comment: it throws the following error : Uncaught reference error : require is not defined

Comment: you need to install phantomjs https://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html and import the phantomjs script library